# How to remove controller from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller:Test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email', 'html'));
    }
    public function study_abroad()
    {
        $data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
        $this->load->view('study-abroad',$data);
    }
}
```

view:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>study-abroad">Study Abroad</a>
```

route.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = 'test';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

$route['(:any)'] = "colleges/index/$1";
$route['college/(:any)'] = "test/college/$1";
$route['study-abroad'] = "test/study_abroad";
```

In this code, I have created a controller having name Test.php where I have load a view file having name study-abroad. Now, I want to remove controller name i.e. Test from my URL. I have defined the path of study abroad in my route file and delete controller name from view file but it redirects me to the wrong page. If I put controller name before view file it will redirect me the actual page. What is the problem behind this?

Comment: Why you want to remove controller from the url?

Comment: I am give this controller name in many pages through which my url is long thats why @PankajMakwana

Comment: can any body help me plsss

Comment: Your code looks ok what is the problem?

Comment: checkout this documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html this may help you

Comment: when I click on the link it redirect me on wrong page but when I put controller name on the link it redirect me the actual page @ankitsuthar

Comment: nothing wrong in your code, Its work for me ,

$route['study-abroad'] = "Controller/study_abroad";

<a href="<?= base_url('study-abroad') ?>">Study Abroad</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this Complete Route file code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['college/(:any)'] = "test/college/$1";
$route['study-abroad'] = "test/study_abroad";
$route['(:any)'] = "colleges/index/$1";

$route['default_controller'] = 'test';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

As indicated, `$route['(:any)']` will match any URL, so place your other custom routes before the other route route

Calling a route in view:

```
<a href="<?= base_url('study-abroad') ?>">Study Abroad</a>
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: @omkara remove test as default controller and try it work then we will see  what to do with that

Comment: I have edit in my route file please look at once if I comment $route['(:any)'] = "colleges/index/$1";
$route['college/(:any)'] = "test/college/$1"; these two route then study-abroad work perfectly what is the reason @ankit suthar

Comment: @omkara Try the updated answer and just paste the route code and try.

Comment: Thanks buddy for helping me. its woking :)

Comment: just one thing that avoids using plane `(any)` in route. always give any name before it

Answer (score 0):

You can set your a route for each url in Code Igniter.
In your `config/routes.php` file, just set each page like this:

```
$route['study-abroad'] = "test/study_abroad";
```

Hope it helps you